# Distribution of $Z=XY$ when $X$ is given

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have a normal distribution. What is the distribution of variable $Z=XY$, when $X$ is given, i.e., distribution of $Z\mid X$?

Does $Z\mid X$ have a normal distribution? Thanks!

Comment: See [Normal Product Distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html)

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are *any* random variables, the distribution of $XY$ given the event $X=c$ is just the distribution of $cY$. Remember that a conditional probability distribution is conditional on a random event (such as $X=c$), not a random variable (such as $X$).

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks very much for your comment and also the kind point. Really helpful. Thanks! :)

Comment: @WaveX Thanks very much!